# Roslyn list of #r references

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

In the Roslyn scripting environment if the user creates scripts he has the ability to reference assemblies like #r "Assembly.dll" or #r "System.Drawing" things like that. Is there a way to get all of these out of a file before executing it? I basically do not want to create a huge security problem when the user has access to like... everything.

Comment: Doesn't seem like much point in stripping out references before executing it.  If you do, the program almost certainly wouldn't execute properly.  The only reason it would would be if they didn't use the reference.  Seems like it'd be a better idea to just not execute the entire thing in such cases.  Also note that a malicious user doesn't need any external assemblies to do all sorts of malicious things if they're running their own code on a machine.  Even without any extra assemblies, your machine is now (potentially) theirs.

Comment: No, I do not want to trim anything in the script, but I want to warn the user if non-standard libraries are referenced using #r. For example if a script wants to have file access via System.IO or something like that. I then want to ask the user before the script is actually executed and if he does not, the program will be terminated.

Comment: `System.IO` is a namespace, not an external reference.  You'd need to cut out the base class library to remove access to `System.IO`.

Comment: Also, don't forget the BCL includes reflection which you could use to execute code from any assembly without a #r. If your concern is security, checking for #r does not protect against it in any way at all. So don't even try.

Comment: This sounds like what you want is Code Access Security, though I don't know if it's applicable to Roslyn scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the list of references that were `#r`'ed, you can access that from [`Compilation.DirectiveReferences`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation.directivereferences).

Comment: thanks for that, although the concerns above are very real and I guess I'll just skip the CAS. Its to the user then to decide if he wants to execute a script or not, i.e. if its secure.